# laravel route uri bug

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I was trying to use:

```
Route::resource('categoria','CategoriaController');
```

And when I look in the controller the model 'Categoria' don't in. Then I look into:

```
php artisan route:list
```

And I see below routes:

```
POST      | categoria                                              | categoria.store               | Redebar\Http\Controllers\CategoriaController@store| web

GET|HEAD  | categoria/create                                       | categoria.create              | Redebar\Http\Controllers\CategoriaController@create                        | web          |

DELETE    | categoria/{categorium}                                 | categoria.destroy             | Redebar\Http\Controllers\CategoriaController@destroy                       | web          |

PUT|PATCH | categoria/{categorium}                                 | categoria.update              | Redebar\Http\Controllers\CategoriaController@update                        | web          |

GET|HEAD  | categoria/{categorium}                                 | categoria.show                | Redebar\Http\Controllers\CategoriaController@show                          | web          |

GET|HEAD  | categoria/{categorium}/edit                            | categoria.edit                | Redebar\Http\Controllers\CategoriaController@edit                          | web

--->"categoria/{categorium}"<-----
```

So I did some tests, and I have discovered that the string "ia" turn into "ium". Example if I write :

```
galeria
```

laravel turn it in :

```
galeria/{galerium}
```

Why this happen, how can I fix this ?

Comment: you don't need to fixed it, its a parameter name which can be replaced by any name in your controller function, so add whatever name you want in your function. If you really want to change this, then make route with specific verb rather than use resource

Comment: `ia` singularizes to `ium` in Latin. Thats why you're seeing the incorrect translation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you  need for localization:

```
// within AppServiceProvider's boot method
Route::resourceVerbs([
    'create' => 'crear',
    'edit' => 'editar',
]);

// register a resource 
Route::resource('fotos', 'PhotoController')

// and the output
/fotos/crear
/fotos/{foto}/editar
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/controllers#restful-localizing-resource-uris

Additionally you can explicitly name route parameters when using resource routes.

```
Route::resource('user', 'AdminUserController', ['parameters' => [
    'user' => 'admin_user'
]]);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/controllers#restful-naming-resource-route-parameters

Comment: Thank you, the trouble was solved with the Additionally :

Route::resource('user', 'AdminUserController', ['parameters' => [
    'user' => 'admin_user'
]]);

I had to change my code to:

Route::resource('categoria','CategoriaController',['parameters' =>['categoria' => 'categoria']]);